# Positioning tikz nodes with same x coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

In the MWE the alignment is not as I expect: e. g. the H (first line) and the A (last line) are not beneath each other although they have both x=0.
With respect to y coordinates everthing is fine (thanks to overlay-beamer-styles).
(I'd like to create a presentation that evolves as if the maths teacher is writing on a classical blackboard. So I came to the idea of using tikz.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[visible on=<1->] at (0,-1) {Here is text.};
\node[visible on=<2->] at (0,-2) {$x=y$};
\node[visible on=<3->] at (0,-3) {$a=b$};
\node[visible on=<4->] at (0,-4) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nodes are aligned to the center. You could set `anchor = west` to have them left-aligned.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[visible on=<1->, anchor = west] at (0,-1) {Here is text.};
\node[visible on=<2->, anchor = west] at (0,-2) {$x=y$};
\node[visible on=<3->, anchor = west] at (0,-3) {$a=b$};
\node[visible on=<4->, anchor = west] at (0,-4) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]